# How to insert a large feature using C# and ST_GEOMETRY in Oracle

Tags: oracle-dbms, st-geometry

I am using the st_polyfromtext command to insert features into an Oracle database like this:

```
INSERT INTO polygon_test VALUES (
```

sde.st_polyfromtext ('polygon ((10.01 20.03, 10.52 40.11, 30.29 41.56,
31.78 10.74, 10.01 20.03))', 0)
);

I am crafting the sql by hand in a C# web service and using OracleConnection and OracleCommand to execute the sql. I am using bind variables (:) and OracleParameter to bind the attribute values i send in with the spatial feature.
My issue is that if the feature is very complex and has alot of vertices then i get an Oracle error about literal string too long.
How can i send this coordinate string into Oracle and have it recognized as a feature when i keep hitting this cap?
I have tried to assign the OracleParameter as a CLOB datatype and then bind the :SHAPE to that but it still balks.

Comment: SDO is not an option at this point in time. Even if it were i think the issue of a lengthy input object would still be present.

Comment: I had a similar problem with PostgreSQL which turned out to be the client, I doubt it in this case. What *is* the maximum length for a string in Oracle communication and can *that* be changed? This is possibly a question for  http://dba.stackexchange.com/ they might know. Even though the question has a spatial component the problem is (possibly) Oracle/SQL related.